# How to select a previous row with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm using pandas to read the data frame, I want to divide the value of a row with the previous value of the same row and so on. For example:

```
1017.0  
1000.0   
 969.0
```

I want 1000/1017 then 969/1000 ... Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**`Series.shift()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) for a specific column or [**`DataFrame.shift()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) for the whole frame:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1017.0, 1000.0, 969.0]})
df.a / df.a.shift()

0         NaN
1    0.983284
2    0.969000
Name: a, dtype: float64
```